# GeoServer query with GeoJSON

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geojson, sql

I'm trying to serve a view of my table after passing a GeoJSON polygon.

Te idea is get all the points inside my polygon passed as GeoJSON.

For this, I've created new SQL view, and a query:

```
select p.id, p.nombre
from points p, (select 1 as id, st_setSRID(st_GeomFromGeoJSON(%polygon%), 4326) as geom) as pol
where st_within(p.geom, pol.geom)
```

where `polygon` is the parameter I want to pass.

I'm getting the error `ERROR: unexpected end of data (at offset 0)` when I'm trying to save the query in GeoServer.
The query is tested in PostGIS and running ok.

Any Idea what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the default value of polygon?

Comment: I've passed '' (two single quotes) as default value in geoserver. What should it be?

Comment: something that st_geomfromgeomjson can parse into a polygon

Answer (score 1):

Fixed passing a 'sample' geoJSON as default value.

```
{ "type": "Polygon", 
"coordinates": [
    [
        [ -4.573988468717024, 40.729307763884464 ],
        [ -2.687283913980384, 40.825389940283088 ],
        [ -2.634875454126589, 40.065467272403055 ],
        [ -4.268272452903218, 39.855833432987872 ],
        [ -4.573988468717024, 40.729307763884464 ] 
    ]
  ]
}
```